# Data URI encoder

Tags: javascript

Review this code for code quality.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Data URI encoder</title>
<style>
#dropbox {
  padding: 18.5px 0;
  max-width: 499px;
  border: 2px dashed #bbb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #bbb;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Data URI encoder</h1>
<p>Select or drag a file to get the Data URI: <input id="fileinput" type="file"></p>
<div id="dropbox"><h3>Drop file here</h3></div>
<p id="filename"></p>
<p><textarea id="content" rows="6" cols="60" onclick="this.select()"></textarea></p>
<p id="filesize"></p>
<script>
var fileinput = document.getElementById("fileinput"),
  dropbox = document.getElementById("dropbox"),
  filename = document.getElementById("filename"),
  content = document.getElementById("content"),
  filesize = document.getElementById("filesize");

function encodeDataURI(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files,
    file = files[0],
    reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = (function() {
    return function(e) {
      content.value = e.target.result;
      filename.textContent = file.name;
      filesize.innerHTML = "Data URI size: " + e.target.result.length + " bytes<br>" + "Original size: " + file.size + " bytes"
    };
  })();

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function handleDragOver(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";
}

dropbox.addEventListener("dragover", handleDragOver, false);
dropbox.addEventListener("drop", encodeDataURI, false);
fileinput.addEventListener("change", encodeDataURI, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

There isn't much here, just a few comments though:

- Most developers I come across use `var` per variable rather than comma separated. It's down to personal preference and code habits though, so you could ignore this one.

  An advantage I see is that it makes variable declaration easier to move around without worrying about the connecting commas.
- I don't see the benefit of using a closure for `reader.onload`. You can simply just assign it a function.
- Further, you can move out the `reader.onload` handler function outside `encodeDataURI`. That way, the code won't generate that handler function for every call of `encodeDataURI`. Optimizing JS engines will do this for you though, but it's best practice if you just code it that way.
- Programming languages were designed for people. Name your variables verbosely. For instance, `e` into `event`. Short variables are only good in the short-term. Long-term, they aren't good for maintenance. Don't worry about file sizes, that's what minifiers are for.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems pretty much picture perfect.

- JS beautifying does nothing, I am guessing you used it
- JS hint has nothing to report except a missing semicolon after `filesize.innerHTML = "`..
- As for using 1 var, I think that is the right thing to do
- As for your closure in `encodeDataURI`, you are accessing `file`, so that is justified.

I can only ask that you share this with the world through a github project or github gist.

On a second thought; your code could use some comments, particularly as to which browsers are supported and what tricks you employ to make that work. Especially this line could use a comment as to which browser uses what:

```
var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files,
```

Comment: Thanks for your review.
I'm a beginner at JavaScript, should I join Github right now?

Comment: Interesting, I think you should.